# How to change woocommerce category product image links

Tags: image, zooming, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce website using as catalog and I just want to make it easy for user to see product image shortly that when they click on every product images in category page, the image show up in full size. Something like zoom image plugin but not in single product page, I want the same in categories page by clicking on thumbnails. 
Can I change the image links in category? And how?

Thanks in advanced